# Resetting MySQL root password

Tags: mysql, password, phpmyadmin

## The Problem

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and I have installed MySQL recently. I have never actually used it yet though. As far as I remember, I never set any password for any user. (If I did, I know what it would be.)

Today I installed phpMyAdmin and found that I was unable to log in to root through phpMyAdmin. I tried to log in to MySQL directly via the terminal without a password:

```
mysql -u root
```

And with the password that I would have set, if I forgot:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

But both of these returned

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

## Attemted Solutions

#### Attempt 1

I tried following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset) guide, I stopped the MySQL demon process, I then started the mysqld daemon process using the `--skip-grant-tables` option. Then when running this command to log in without the password:

```
mysql -u root
```

Instead of arriving at the `mysql>` prompt, I was faced with the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 
'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

#### Attempt 2

I tried to uninstall MySQL using:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client
```

And then I tried to reinstall MySQL using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client
```

And then tried to set a password like this:

```
mysqladmin -u root password my-new-password
```

Yet I was once again stumped with an error message:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost''
```

#### My fellow programmers, I am absolutely clueless as to where to head from here in the continuation of my quest to obtain the powers of MySQL...

## Edit

After using `sudo` (as per vidarlo's answer) I was able to access my databases, and I managed to change my password using this:

```
mysql> update user set authentication_string=password("Z4hVdwn9qZ") 
       where user='root';
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1
```

But phpMyAdmin still won't log in and returns the error

```
#1698 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Comment: After purging and reinstalling mysql, were you able to access mysql using `mysql -u root` before trying to set a password?

Comment: @LienhartWoitok Nope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

MariaDB uses Unix socket authentication, which means you're authenticated as the user starting the mysql client.

You can read more about it in [MariaDB's documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/).

Comment: I managed to use this to access my databases and change the root password using the command line, but phpMyAdmin still says `#1698 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`